# ios app works on phone but not on simualator

Tags: ios, sqlite

i have a sqlite file in the main bundle , i read the file with the code

```
_databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainDB" ofType:@"db" inDirectory:@""];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Database Not Found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [av show];
}
```

i changed mainDB.db file, added the new one in xcode > Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Now the app works on iPhone but not on simulator,
On Simulator, file is there, sqlite3_open is OK, but sqlite3_pepare_v2 is not going through
I have a feeling that somwhow the  old file is still stuck somewhere in the Simulator app, i Tried resetting Simulator but no luck.
Any Suggestions ?

Comment: What is the error?  You cannot copy files into the main bundle on the device, so I'm assuming you worded that improperly and that's not the error.

Comment: file is already in main bundle, i only read that DB i don't write to the main bundle, when i changed my DB file, the app works fine on the device but not on simulator, on Simulator there's no error as i check if file exists or when sqlite3_open, but i get an error on sqlite3_prepare_v2, PS. same code works on iphone with my new DB

Comment: My only thought is that they are running two different versions of the database.  Did you run a clean and rebuild before putting it on both device and simulator?  If that is not it then I'm at a loss, I don't have the knowledge to delve into sqlite errors.

Comment: I also have the thought that the old file is in the simulator mainBundle not the new one. I tried resetting though, but no luck

Comment: Did the app work in the simulator before? Did you try a clean build?

Comment: it was working fine on the simulator, what do you exactly mean a clean build ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting application from simulator and reinstall?